# Programmaticaly remove a member from a group

Tags: 8, group

Using the Group module, what is the function to remove a user from a group using its user ID and the group ID?

Answer (score 4):

The entity type interface (`GroupInterface`) has a `removeMember` method; all you need are the relevant entity objects:

```
if ($account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($user_id)) {
  if ($group = \Drupal\group\Entity\Group::load($group_id)) {
    $group->removeMember($account);
  }
}
```

Comment: I knew it had to be that simple! I was looking for a removeMember() method then after your answer I decided to look at the version I was using.... Thanks!

Comment: Do we have something like og_expire for drupal 8? Basically how to remove the users from the group automatically after a certain number of days?

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering, there is also `$group->addMemeber($account);`